# PHP new line every X characters in long characters sequence

Tags: php, string

How can I add a new line characters (\n\r) in txt file every 10 characters?

What I have is a long sequence of characters, and I like to create a new line for each 10 characters.

in example, let's say I have that sequence of characters:

```
FadE4fh73d4F3fab5FnF4fbTKhuS591F60b55hsE
```

and I like to convert it to that:

```
FadE4fh73d
4F3fab5FnF
4fbTKhuS59
1F60b55hsE
```

How can I do that ?

I know that I can use a loop for that, but because the above string is an example and my string that I have to split it is really very very long, just I wander if there is any faster and more easy way to spit my string.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`chunk_split($string, 10)`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php for more info

Comment: I know that this is not a part of the question, but as a reference to other people: one can also use [wordwrap](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) if you are dealing with words and don't want it to be splitted by the function.

Comment: I stumbled over this and found that `chunk_split()` will always add the break sequence to the last chunk, too. This might lead to unexpected results, so be aware.

Answer (score 7):

using `chunk_split()`:

```
$str = chunk_split($str, 10, "\n\r");
```

or using [this](http://regexr.com?2vgf7) regex:

```
$str = preg_replace("/(.{10})/", "$1\n\r", $str);
```

---

And by the way did you mean `\r\n` (New line in Windows environment) by `\n\r`?
if so then the third argument for `chunk_split()` can be omitted.

Comment: `chunk_split` returns a **string**. Have a look at the third parameter of this function, it should be: `$str = chunk_split($str, 10, '\n\r');`

Comment: @Felix: me too, but I trapped in such cases too often, now I know ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$foo = '01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789';
$result = chunk_split ($foo, 10, "\r\n");
echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the use of `chunk_split()` might have unwanted consequences, as the break sequence is always added to the end once again.

You can instead use a combination of [`str_split()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.str-split.php) and [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.implode.php) to first split the string every X characters and then recombine it with a break sequence. By using `implode()`, the break sequence will not be added to the end, again.

I've build a helper function who does this for me after 75 chars:

```php
function createFold($s, $b = '\\n ') {
    $chunks = str_split($s, 75);
    return implode($b, $chunks);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<b><</b>?<b>php</b><br/>
$body=$row['details'];<br/>
$str = chunk_split($body, 14, "<b><</b><b>br</b><b>/</b>");<br/>

echo $str;<br/>
?
```

Comment: Please never post code-only answers a year and a half after a duplicate solution is already provided.  Downvoted because this post adds no value to the page.